# MIPS assembly, Multiplication error for finding primes above 2^16

Tags: assembly, mips, primes, multiplication

To start off this is a homework assignment.  The goal is to find Mersenne Primes but once the program gets to 2^17 the multiplication answers are incorrect.  I have ran out of ideas on what to do.

```
for (i=1;i<=p-2;i++)
   s = ((s*s)-2)%m
```

Above is the java equivalent of the code.
The Mips part no longer calculates s*s correctly when s is equal to 2^17.  I've tried every variation of the multiply macro that I could find, however none of them seem to fix this problem.  I think it has to do with overflow, but I'm stuck.  Any help is appreciated.

```
    mul     $t2,$t2,$t2
    subu    $t2,$t2,2
    divu    $t2,$t3
    mfhi    $t7
    move    $t2,$t7
    addu    $t5,$t5,1
    ble $t5,$t6,third
    addu    $t5,$t5,1
    beqz    $t2,YES
    bgtz    $t2,NO
```

Comment: How high do you have to go? 2^17 is pretty high.

Comment: I need to be able to check 2^31, the rest of the code works perfectly, just that part of the multiplication.

Comment: (2^17) x (2^17) = 2^34, which is bigger than the 32 bit registers used in the mips. Try using multu $t2,$t2 to see if it creates a 64 bit product in $hi, $lo on your version of the mips cpu. There doesn't seem to be a 64 bit by 32 bit divide, so you'll need to do some type of extended precision code.

Comment: Nope that didn't work, what would extended precision code be?

Comment: @rcgldr, forgot to add the tag

Answer (score 1):

So here's what I'm thinking.

You are using the `mul` instruction which throws out the higher word of a multiplication.

If instead you use the `mult` instruction it will keep the high-word in the HI register and the low word in the LO register.

From there you have a 64-bit value that is split up between the 32-bit HI and LO registers.

To subtract 2, subtract 2 first from the low word, and if it goes below zero subtract 1 from the high word.

Performing modulus of m isn't very easy in the general case. However, it could be OK if m is a power of 2.

Comment: `MUL` is an actual instruction in the MIPS32 ISA (opcode %011100, function %000010).

Comment: @Michael Huh. My bad.

Comment: This was something I had tried.  The multiplication throws 587513809 into the lo register and 2 into the hi.  9177448401 is the number I need to get.

Comment: (2^32 * 2) + 587513809 = 9177448401. If the largest value for m is less than 2^16, it would simplify trying to do an extended precision divide. You start off with the upper 16 bits of the dividend, do a divide, store the quotient, then the next dividend = (remainder<<16) + next 16 bits of dividend.